# How can I block the google chrome dino game easter egg?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, blocking, macbook-air

I am using on chrome on a Macbook Air if that helps. I know that the game can be blocked on windows, but I'd like to block it on my macbook air.

Answer (score 0):

Create a policy file as oulined [here](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates):

> Policies are defined on a Mac in a plist (property list) file. The
>   latest plist template is included in the Google Chrome/Chromium
>   installer package.  To find the plist:
>
> 1. Download Google Chrome
> 2. Open the bundle and find the Configuration folder
> 3. Open a file called com.google.Chrome.manifest. This is the latest plist template.
> 4. Review the plist template.
> 5. Use the template to create your own plist file.
> 6. Create your own plist file with appropriate policies based on the plist template. Use the property list editor of your choice.
> 7. Use your system management tool to push the configuration file to client Macs.

The policy you need to set is `AllowDinosaurEasterEgg` as documented [here](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AllowDinosaurEasterEgg).